# How to manage large initial application data in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I am working on a Symfony 2 application that requires quite a lot of initial data. A couple of thousand rows easily. What are good ways of managing this dataset?

I have been trying with Docrine Migrations but it's a bit of a pain. The data is loaded once and you can't reload. If there was a bug in the data you need another migration to find and correct it, etcetera.

I have also been reading up on Doctrine Fixtures. This looks more like what I need, but it required me to write PHP code that creates all my data as entities. With several thousand entries, this is going to be a major pain.

Any better options?

Comment: you mean you really have to literally have all that rows in memory?

Comment: Doctrine fixtures would really be the way to go. Where are all those data coming from?

Comment: It is the initial dataset for my application. It is not test/fixture data. The data is needed by all developers working on the application (everyone has their own database) and when the application goes to staging or production, this data also needs to be present.

Comment: may be simpler to create a dump of database and store it?

Comment: @forgottenbas We tried that. It doesn't hold up under schema changes. We already use Doctrine Migrations for schema changes.

Comment: When schema changes, generate a new dump.

Comment: Your dump does not have to contain the table structs, just the insert statements, potentially preceded by TRUNCATE / DELETE CASCADE .

Answer (score 2):

If the data is stored in a file, you can use [Doctrine Data Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) to import the data from that file.

You just write the fixture class to parse the data file, set the data on a new entity, and persit the entity.

For example, if the data was stored in a Yaml file, something like this would work:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadIntialData.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

class LoadIntialData implements FixtureInterface {

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $filename =
            __DIR__ .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Resources/data/data.yml';

        $yml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($filename));
        foreach ($yml as $data) {
            $entity = new MyEntity();

            $entity->setFoo($data['foo']);
            $entity->setBar($data['bar']);

            $manager->persist($entity);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: if the yml is correctly formatted, you can use alice too: https://github.com/nelmio/alice

Comment: Would it be possible to do something similar to import multiple, related entities from the same file?

Comment: @oflannabhra Yes, you can do that. You can also do it with separate fixtures and data files for each entity. If you have related entities, take a look at the [Sharing Objects between Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures) section of the docs

Comment: I have the same problem. How would you load data of 100K rows that then  is referenced in other entities. Do you think it will work with fixture method addReference ? What about memory ?